# Setting a key & value in local storage not working

Tags: node.js, local-storage

I'm trying to set a key & value in local storage on the browser with NodeJS using the localStorage module.
For some reason, it is not setting the storage in my browser: https://gyazo.com/c68a6728eedc434c6fb6ca9f3119d096

My code is:

```
const localStorage = require('localStorage');

localStorage.setItem('myKey', 'myValue');
myValue = localStorage.getItem('myKey');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you referring to 2 different things.

1. Using localStorage in node.js, make sure that you have associated it with a database schema/model.
2. In storing in your browser, you might mean session or cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Node and browsers provide different javascript environments. So I think localStorages you set in Node can't impact the window.localStorage, except for sending localStorages from server to client, then you assign window.localStorage with these values.
Maybe here you want to establish a connection over client and server, you should use cookie or session, not localStorage.